# create a many to many or has many relationship in yii framework

Tags: yii

[image: relationship digram]

How can i create a relationship between these tables
and show in gridview? Basically i wanna show userjobs in users gridview 
like this

```
username password job
wiki     123      senior developer
john     44       junior developer
vicky    44       Marketing Manager
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use [automatic code generation - Gii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.gii) to create the models, the controller and the admin grid for you.

Once this is done you can fine tune the design if needed.